Firebase notifications PWA (cloud messaging)
i wanted to ask if someone else did some implementation on PWA push notifications.
I was trying to implement it via cloud messaging and everything is working but only on some devices and its kinda buggy experience. Im using for sending the firebase console on web.
Technology:
JS, React, PWA, Firebase cloud messaging
So what i have implemented:

Firebase-messaging-sw.js
firebase.js (which contains logic for init firebase + notifications allowance)

1.service worker
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js");
// eslint-disable-next-line
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js");
// eslint-disable-next-line
importScripts(`/offline-sw.js`);

self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {
  self.skipWaiting(); // Force activation
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (e) => {
  e.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      // Claim all clients to ensure the new service worker takes control immediately
      await self.clients.claim();
    })()
  );
});(

firebase.initializeApp({
  HIDDEN_VALUES
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
   console.log("[service-worker] Received background message ", payload);
   return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {
   body: payload.notification.body,
   tag: payload.notification.tag || null,
   icon: payload.notification.icon || "192x192.png",
   image: payload.notification.image || null,
   });
 });



firebase.js

import { initializeApp } from "@firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "@firebase/messaging";
import mixpanel from "mixpanel-browser";

const firebaseConfig = {
  HIDDEN_VALUES
};

let firebase;
try {
  firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error initializing Firebase:", error);
}

// serviceWorker.js
export const registerFirebaseMessagingSw = async () => {
  if (navigator && typeof navigator.serviceWorker !== "undefined") {
    try {
      const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      console.log("Firebase messaging service worker registered", registration);
      return registration;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error registering Firebase messaging service worker:", error);
    }
  }
};

export const areNotificationsAllowed = () => {
  try {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
      return;
    }

    let permission = false;
    switch (Notification.permission) {
      case "granted":
        permission = true;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return permission;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};

let messaging;
try {
  if (firebase) {
    messaging = getMessaging(firebase);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error getting Firebase messaging:", error);
}

const setupNotifications = async () => {
  const registration = await registerFirebaseMessagingSw();
  if (!registration || !messaging) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    // Request permission for notifications
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission === "granted") {
      console.log("Notification permission granted.");
      // Get the FCM token
      const token = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: "PLACEHOLDER",
        serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
      });
      mixpanel.track("Notification permission granted", { token: token });
    } else {
      mixpanel.track("Notification permission denied");
      console.error("Notification permission denied.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    mixpanel.track("Error setting up notifications", { error: error });
    console.error("Error setting up notifications:", error);
  }
};

export { messaging, setupNotifications };

This is all working, i can subscribe to notifications and when i send notification via firebase console it all working, but only for some specific devices. For example this implementation of the worker is causing to send notifications 2 times for each user ... which is wrong since it doesnt make sense to be showing 2 times. I read that its caused by notification property which is triggering also default listener for firebase which is implemented by defining the firebase in code..
but when i decide to remove this
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
   console.log("[service-worker] Received background message ", payload);
   return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {
   body: payload.notification.body,
   tag: payload.notification.tag || null,
   icon: payload.notification.icon || "192x192.png",
   image: payload.notification.image || null,
   });
 });

and keep only the default one from Firebase, im not able to receive on android device (the outdated one) also in this case i would not be able to set the icon if i keep only default)
another approach which was not showing the notificaton on android is the implementation with "push" listener
// this is generic push event listener for any service
// self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
//   const dataText = event.data.text();
//   const data = JSON.parse(dataText);

//   event.waitUntil(
//     self.registration.showNotification(data.notification.title, {
//       body: data.notification.body,
//       tag: data.notification.tag || null,
//       icon: data.notification.icon || "192x192.png",
//       image: data.notification.image || null,
//     })
//   );
// });

In this situation it works for majority of devices but sometimes it decide to not and for example for old androids it dont sending anything ... which is again wrong.
So i got 3 approaches and all of them have some bugs.

onBackgroundMessage


Sending double notifications for all of the devices


push event listener


Dont working for some androids and sometimes dont send it on Ios


Retaining on firebase (so none of the custom implementation)


Dont work for some androids and losing ability to set icon.

im really confused why its behave like this even i followed up docs and tried different approaches still leading to bugs.
I want to be able to send notifications via Firebase UI console on web and recieve it on all subsribed devices and only once for each send..  (so how it should work by common sense)
Would be really glad if someone will be able to help me to figure out what is wrong

Did you solve this? If yes, does it work even if the Android device is in doze mode?
